# Google Analytics event with time on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm currently sending a click event into Google Analytics using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons');
    });
});
```

It works just fine.

However, I want the value to be the minutes of how long the user has on the page.

This means, it will track how many minutes it took the user to click the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //current time at document ready
    var past = new Date().getTime();

    $('#button').on('click', function() {

        //how much minutes passed when button clicked 
       timeElapsedInMin = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - past) / 60000);
        ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons', timeElapsedInMin);
    });

});
```

Comment: Does a minute last 100 seconds? It's what your code seems to do. Why not just `Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - past) / 1000)`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your code, and it does count the time on page, as I did an alert with timeElapsedInMin, and it shows it, however, it no longer pushes the event into Google Analytics.

Comment: I actually got it to work. Not sure what was wrong, but I've used basically the same code. However, the only thing I would like to change is that it doesn't have the decimal cases. Meaning, if it was clicked before the first minute, to be 0, 1min to 1.99 it would show 1, 2 to 2.99 it would show 2, and so on...

Comment: then timeElapsedInMin  should be  Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - past) / 60000); , updated the answer

Comment: Tahat worked great! Thank you so much for your help :)